# Getting error unexpected alert open: when tried to take screenshot of alert

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is browser alert when i pass incorrect data in field and click on finish.
After clicking on finish i have written takescreenshot method to take snap of window but i am getting error on screenshot method.that unexpected alert open.

Comment: This is quite vague could you please elaborate on the issue, and let us know what you have tried so we can help?

Comment: I am getting browser alert on some event and when i am trying to capture screenshot of alert and getting error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open:

Comment: You need to handle the alert... what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not handle alerts shown by the browser the `UnhandledAlertException` is thrown. If you expect the alert to be shown, you need to switch to it via:

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Then you can take the screenshot.